# Can I say what is this means?

Tags: grammaticality

I think **what does this mean** is correct grammatically. But can I say:

> what is this means?

or

> Is that means you blah blah.

Comment: Nope. Stick with *does*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form of both questions would be:

> What **does** this **mean**?

and:

> **Does** that **mean** you ...?

Notice that apart from using *does* instead of *is*, we also use *mean* instead of *mean**s***.